# how to update item in angular 2 using button click?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

could you please tell me how to update item in angular 2 using button click ?I am adding item in `list` with `delete` and `edit` button. When I click `edit` button I set the current item `text` in input field with `update` button. I want to update `text` of selected item after click of `update` button.

here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/F4fk8VAPzu24P8wRBY5A?p=preview

```
 deleteItem(item){
    console.log(item);
    var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.items.splice(index,1);
  }

  editItem(item){
    this.update =true;
    console.log(item);
    var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.val=this.items[index];

  }

  updateItem(){

  }
```

Comment: yes I accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use toggle concept to achieve this.

```
<button (click)="addItem(name)">ADD Item</button>
   <button *ngIf="update" (click)="updateItem()">Update</button>
    <input type="text" name="" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
     <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
        <span  *ngIf="!item.editMode">{{item.name}}</span>
        <input type="text"  *ngIf="item.editMode" [(ngModel)]="item.name"/>
         <button (click)="deleteItem(item)">X</button>
         <button (click)="item.editMode= !item.editMode">Edit</button>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

Updated [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zwPZRXqybCtBb42kMgVX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , have **currentIndex** as global variable to keep track of current index;

```
currentIndex=0;
editItem(item){
this.update =true;
console.log(item);
var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
this.currentIndex = index;
this.val=this.items[index];
}

updateItem(){
  this.items[this.currentIndex] = this.val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use global variables

You have created index variable inside editItem(); use this.index instead.
https://plnkr.co/edit/nllh0YZzcMACexiMZwFy?p=preview

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <button (click)="addItem()">ADD Item</button>
   <button *ngIf="update" (click)="updateItem()">Update</button>
    <input type="text" name="" (keyup)="onKeyP($event)" [value]="val"/>
     <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
         <button (click)="deleteItem(item)">X</button>
         <button (click)="editItem(item)">Edit</button>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>

  `,
})
export class App {
   title = 'Times point';
  name ="hellxo";
  val ="defual";
  items=[];
  update=false;
  onKeyP(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.val=event.target.value
  }

  addItem(){
    if(this.val){
    this.items.push(this.val);
    this.val ='';
    }
  }
  deleteItem(item){
    console.log(item);
    var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.items.splice(index,1);
  }

  editItem(item){
    this.update =true;
    console.log(item);
    var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
    this.val=this.items[index];

  }

  updateItem(){

  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```